# GroupBy Query Which Shows Related Data In Addition to Grouping Clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ugh, I know it's a terrible title, but I can't think of a way to summarize my question in a simple statement. It's a fairly basic T-SQL query question but I haven't used T-SQL much in the last year or so and my brain simply doesn't want to work today.

Basically I have a table with usernames (email address) and a client id. There can't be multiple emails per client, but there can be multiple emails for different clients. I'm trying to do a group on email addresses to get a count of how many emails are associated with 1 or more clients - that's the easy part. Where I'm struggling is trying to also list which client ids the email address is associated to.

For example, I have this query which gives me 1/2 of what I'm looking for:

```
select  UserName, COUNT(*)
from    UserTable
group by UserName
having COUNT(*) > 1
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

But I would also like to have either a row-per client, or even just multiple new columns showing each client id the email address is associated with such as:

```
user1@test.com 3
user1@test.com 34
user1@test.com 9
```

OR

```
user1@test.com 3 34 9
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: Are you looking for something like:  `SELECT UserName, ClientID FROM UserTable GROUP BY UserName, ClientID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc`?

Comment: @Linger - Negative. That query would show 0 results since it's also goruping by the client id. I need only the username grouped but the result set to include the client ids for the username. Thanks for the input however.

Comment: that code is not 1 or more

Comment: @Blam - Correct, I'm only interested in the cases where a single username is associated with at minimum 2 client ids.

Comment: Then fix the text of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL-Server, you can use the COUNT window function:

```
SELECT UserName, UserId, COUNT(UserId) OVER (PARTITION BY UserName) AS Counts
FROM UserTable
```

Then to pick out only those with a count greater than 1:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT UserName, UserId, COUNT(UserId) OVER (PARTITION BY UserName) AS Counts
  FROM UserTable
) rows
WHERE rows.Counts > 1
```

To get them into the second format, you'd need to use some [row concatenation strategy](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) - FOR XML PATH is a popular one.

Comment: Ah yes, this does the trick. So does the FOR XML PATH however I marked this as answer since the approach isn't as convoluted and achieves my goals. Thanks for the expediency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FOR XML PATH:

```
Select UserName, COUNT(*), 
    substring(
        (
            Select ','+clientID  AS [text()]
            From UserTable UTI
            Where UTI.UserName = UTO.UserName
            ORDER BY UTI.clientID
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000)
From UserTable UTO
group by UserName
having COUNT(*) > 1
order by COUNT(*) desc
```